# How to subtract from a column from 2 tables with a same column

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have 2 tables Named :  Stock and Order

table : Stock

```
+-----------+-----------+
|   Item    |   Number  |
+-----------+-----------+
|   A       |      20   | 
|   B       |       7   |
|   C       |      11   | 
|   D       |      13   |
+-----------+-----------+
```

table : Order

```
+-----------+-----------+
|   Item    |   Number  |
+-----------+-----------+
|   A       |       8   | 
|   B       |       2   |
|   C       |       5   | 
|   D       |       9   |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I need to subtract the column number from stock to order.

The result would be :

table : Stock

```
+-----------+-----------+
|   Item    |   Number  |
+-----------+-----------+
|   A       |      12   | 
|   B       |       5   |
|   C       |       6   | 
|   D       |       4   |
+-----------+-----------+
```

I have tried using

```
SELECT item , number=
(
  (SELECT number FROM stock)-(SELECT number from order))
  FROM order;
```

Unfortunately it does not work, please help me!
And pardon for the formatting.

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN` the two tables together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT B.Item,A.Number - B.Number FROM
Stock A
INNER JOIN Order B 
ON A.Item=B.Item
```

Answer (score 2):

If two tables are in 1:1 relation -> try this:

```
SELECT s.item, s.number - o.number
FROM stock s
JOIN order o
    ON s.item = o.item
```

Otherwise:

```
SELECT s.item,
s.number - ISNULL(
    (SELECT SUM(o.number)
    FROM order o
    WHERE o.item = s.item), 0)
FROM stock s
```